# problem to import load data infile

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

I am trying to load data into mysql database form text file.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'P:\file.txt' INTO TABLE table_january
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
```

> error code: 1148. The used command is note allowed with this MySQL

MySQL version 8.0.19.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437689/error-1148-the-used-command-is-not-allowed-with-this-mysql-version

Comment: Use a forward slash in path names.  (Yes, even on Windows.)

Answer (score 0):

looks like this an issue with [mysql workbench 8](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91891) . Try this workaround.
1. locate or create your [my.cnf file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html). E.g. if you're on a unix platform, look for `~/.my.cnf` and create it if it doesn't exist.
2. update my.cnf to contain

```
[client]
port        = 3306
[mysqld]
port        = 3306
secure_file_priv=''
local-infile = 1
```

3. restart the MySQL server.

Comment: Link-only posts are discouraged; please see [answer]. If you think one of the workarounds at your link is the solution, you are encouraged to explain it fully here with your own helpful additions & attribution. Welcome to the network :)